# I can't understand how to solve an inequality with 3rd degree polynomials

Tags: inequality

I have a big doubt, basically I'm trying to solve two different inequalities (I know the solutions) but I have to solve them using two different methods or I can't get the right solution.

The first is: $2x^3-6x^2>0$
the solution here is: $x>3$
the method I used is: $2x^2(x-3)>0$
$2x^2>0 → x>0$
and $x-3>0 → x>3$
then I used this kind of table to unify the solutions:

---0---3---

....|_____ (it means x>0)

........|__ (it means x>3)

and the result is x>3

the second inequality is: $2x^3-8x>0$
the solution is: $-2<x<0$ and $x>2$
the method I used is: $x(2x^2-8)>0$
$x>0$
$2x^2-8>0 → x=+2$, $-2 → x<-2 and x>2$

in this case I used I signs table to unify the solutions:

---(-2)---0---2---

..-..|..-.|.+.|.+.

..+..|..-.|.-.|.+.

---

..-..|..+.|.-.|.+.

and the result is right : -22

but for examble if I use a signs table for the first inequality the result is wrong.. it would be x<0 and x>3
---0---3---

.-.|.+.|.+.

.-.|.-.|.+.

---

.+.|.-.|.+.

the same happens when I use the first type of table for the second inequality.. the solution would be x>2

---(-2)---0---2---

...........|_____ (it means x>2)

___|..........|--- (it means x<-2 and x>2)

where am I doing wrong?
any kind of help will be very much appreciated, have a good day :)

Comment: not putting comma's in your post is a way you are going wrong x=-2,2 is not x=-22.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each factor alone, decide where it's +,- and 0, then count the number of minuses in each column. If even number of minuses then the product is +, if odd number of minuses then - and if there's a $0$ anywhere then it's $0$.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}factor\backslash x&&0&&3\\\hline x&-&0&+&+&+\\x&-&0&+&+&+\\x-3&-&-&-&0&+\\\hline product &-&0&-&0&+\end{array}$$

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer! Can I ask you a clarification?
When I factor inequalities I can't use the first type of table in order to unify the partial solutions right? Only the signs table works, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the "first type of table" is. Try to take out as low order factors as you can, because there is less risk to make mistakes the simpler (lower order) they are. Then try and be systematic and use a clear way of keeping track of which factors are which so you don't accidentally mix them up or take some of them twice.

Comment: this was the first type of table:

---0---3---


....|_____ (it means x>0)

........|__ (it means x>3)

in this case I take only the part with two lines as the solution. 
It's a different kind of table, without signs and considering just the common solutions. At this point I suppose it works only for systems of equations/inequalities.
I'm sorry I can't show you the table, but it's just the first I talked about in this post.

Comment: The thing is that you need to count the number of negative factors to keep track of the sign. So it is better to be clear what is + and what is - because you are going to need to count them for each interval.

Comment: -1 is negative, $-1 \cdot -1 = 1$ and $-1 \cdot -1 \cdot -1 = -1$ et.c.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is right:
$$2x^2(x-3)>0.$$

Now draw the $x$-axis and take there to points $0$ and $3$.

Signs of the expression $x^2(x-3)$ they are:
$$-----(0)-----(3)++++++,$$
which gives the answer: $x>3$.